# wget with wild characters [*.cpp]

Tags: wget

How to use wild characters in wget ?
e.g. wget http://abc.com/programs/*.cpp

Thanks

Comment: Not a good idea to reveal your email address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A.cpp http://abc.com/programs/
```

based on http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/use-wget-to-download-multiple-files-with-wildcards-603486/. Depending on the permissions set on the server, it may or may not work.

Comment: I tried it, however it's not working ! getting below error-ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Comment: That's the problem they ran into on the page I found. Can you download an individual file explicitly, i.e. `wget http://abc.com/programs/file.cpp`? If not, you'll have to investigate the folder permissions on your server. Also notice my edit, you might need the --no-parent flag.

Comment: Also, add -nd not to create remote directory structure on local system.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done for http because http does not allow globbing or listing in any form. It will only work for ftp addresses (afaik.)

If you need to do this, though, it depends on the situation. You may be able to tell wget to crawl links (such as on a directory listing) but it would be a bit more complex than that.